# How to automatically initialize a static variable that call InetAddress.getLocalHost()?

Tags: java, junit

following this short tutorial http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0095.html I am trying to get my client **IP Address**.

The only difference from the tutorial is that I want that my IP address is put inside a **static variable** so I do in the following way:

```
private static InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

But Eclipse give me the following error message: **Unhandled exception type UnknownHostException**

So, I think, that the problem is that I can't call this code:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

into a static variable but I have first to declare the static variable and then initialize it into every method that use it.

The problem that I need it into a JUnit test and this is very bad initialize it every time into all @test method !!!

So, what can I do to avoid initializing it in every test method? There is some other way to initialize it only once? Can I create a initialization method that will automatically execute at the beginning when I run my test class? How?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to initialize on static block,

```
private static InetAddress thisIp;

static{
    try {
        thisIp  = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static initialization block:

```
class YourClass {

    private static InetAddress thisIp;

    static {
      try {
        thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        Logger.log(ex);
      } finally {
        ...
      }
    }
   ...
}
```

This block can go at any point in the class, outside of any method.

Comment: mmm, what is it? how?